# Using Default Credentials to Authenticate for the Gmail API

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, credentials

### Summary:

The example for using the Gmail API in Go includes code for reading credentials from a known JSON file inside the filesystem. I would like to take advantage of Application Default Credentials (ADC) since we're deploying to k8s with access to the Gmail API.

### Code:

Please find an excerpt from the [full demo](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/go-samples/blob/master/gmail/quickstart/quickstart.go) below:

```golang
//error handling omited for brevity
b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("credentials.json")
config, _ := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, gmail.GmailReadonlyScope) //is it possible to replace this?
client := getClient(config)
srv, _ := gmail.New(client)
```

How can I replace line 2 in the excerpt to get the same configuration but without using an explicit JSON credentials file?

Comment: Please always try to read [the docs](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1) of the package you're about to use instead of rushing to StackOverflow. What you're after, is stated right in the "Creating client" section. You might want to read and think through [this essay](https://www.whathaveyoutried.com/), thanks.

Comment: You can print an access token using [`gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token)  . Use it to make requests to the API, instead of reading from the file.

Answer (score -1):

You can print an access token using [gcloud auth application-default print-access-token](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) . Use it to make requests to the API, instead of reading from the file. – Aerials

Answer (score -1):

Just a note about printing an access token with gcloud auth, the application-default login will need to have scopes for accessing the Gmail API using --scopes. The default OpenID client used by the gcloud SDK will not be allowed to do this, during the OAuth flow, the request is blocked by Google with something like "this app is banned". --client-id-file can be used as well to use a different OpenID client, but this may not be much more convenient than the example code with token management.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34758128)